# What happens when an attack with a raider drops a hero to 0 hp?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death

So, imagine you are hit by a monster and dropped down to 0 hp. But then the same attack also requires you to make a Constitution save or take extra damage. Is this attack treated as a single damage and you stay at 0 hp, or what I think, you are dropped to 0 hp from the normal attack, then you make a Con save and if you fail it, you take the extra damage causing the character to receive a failed death save?

Edit: As my question was deleted because there is a similar one, but there is no answer to this exact circumstance. Here we have one attack that requires an attack roll for the 1st portion of damage and then a save for the additional damage. I cannot find an answer that explains this situation!

Comment: Hi, I changed the dupe target to one I think actually cover your question. If it doesn't, do please explain to us how.

Comment: And as a note on practice and terminology; your question wasn't deleted, it was closed as a duplicate, which we consider a good thing as it will help others find the other question. Also, you don't need to signal your edits, there's a full revision history built into the site, see [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454) for more details.

Comment: The current dupe question answers this situation exactly.